# Grails filter sequence

Tags: grails, filter

In my Grails application I have two filters which protect all my controllers for every action (controllers: '*', action: '*'). How can I specify that filter1 is executed before filter2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that specifying *dependsOn* property in your filter class, like this:

```
class SecondFilters {
    def dependsOn = [FirstFilters]
    def filters = { ... }
}
```